# ¿Cómo editar una fila de un DataTable en JQUERY del lado del cliente?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Estoy trabajando en la edición de una fila de un DataTable pero los ejemplos que he encontrado hasta el momento, son utilazando AJAX, mi requerimiento es que del lado del cliente pueda insertar, eliminar y modificar los registros y guardarlos en una variable de angularjs $scope para que posteriormente mande el objeto en un JSON hacia el servidor. Este es el código que estoy utilizando.

```
var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
     table: "#grid",
     idSrc:  'id',
     fields: [ {
             label: "numPrograma:",
             name: "numPrograma"
         }, {
             label: "chrClavePresupuestalPro",
             name: "chrClavePresupuestalPro"
         }, {
             label: "chrNombrePrograma:",
             name: "chrNombrePrograma"
         }, {
             label: "dependencia:",
             name: "dependencia"
         }, {
             label: "nomTitular:",
             name: "nomTitular"
         }, {
             label: "cargo",
             name: "cargo",
         }, {
             label: "tel",
             name: "tel"
         }, {
             label: "extension",
             name: "extension"
         }, {
             label: "correo",
             name: "correo"
         }, {
             label: "itercambio",
             name: "itercambio"
         }

     ]
 } );

var table = $('#grid').DataTable( {
 "data":datosParam,
 "bFilter": false,
 "language": {
        url: '/localisation/mx_MX.json'
    },
       "columns": [
        { "data": "numPrograma" },
        { "data": "chrClavePresupuestalPro" }, 
        { "data": "chrNombrePrograma" },
        { "data": "dependencia" },     
        { "data": "nomTitular" },
        { "data": "cargo" },     
        { "data": "tel" },   
        { "data": "extension" },
        { "data": "correo" },    
        { "data": "itercambio" },
            ],
            select: {
                style:    'os',
                selector: 'td:first-child'
            }
   }  
);
```

Comment: Disculpa, quizás me confundí un poco, tu quieres guardar en un array de objetos, la cantidad que tu quieras, y luego cuando decidas enviarlas al servidor?

Comment: Hola, si, es precisamente lo que quiero, espero me puedas ayudar. saludos

Comment: Podrías editar le contenido y poner el código html para ver un poco mas lo que haces?

Comment: Hola lo que solicitas es mas complicado de lo que parece, mi idea es que después de editarlos  guardes los datos en un `input hidden` que tenga el ng-model, para que asi hagas lo que quieras con Angular.  (esto claro es el caso obvio y nada profesional)